# Cambiar el color de una area seleccionada de una imagen al pasar el mouse

Tags: hover

Tengo una imagen donde puedo poner varios enlaces y darle la forma con el poligono, pero lo que necesito es que al pasar el mouse, esta área se rellene con un background transparente. También necesito que sea responsivo los sectores.

Este el código:

```
<html>
<body>
<img src="images/caja-packagin.jpg" usemap="#Map">
<map name="Map">
<area shape="poly" coords="76,396,131,433,160,426,151,411,147,199,273,196,310,209,311,298,412,295,412,66,235,61,131,57,77,64,76,393,75,400" href="#enlacedeprueba">
</map>
</body>
</html>
```

Necesito colorear el sector al hacer hover

Comment: ¿Podrías incluir el código que tienes hasta el momento? Ahora mismo no está muy claro lo que preguntas...

Comment: Como dice @FranciscoRomero inserta el código, así veremos lo que llevas intentado y la tecnología que estas utilizando para poder ayudarte

Answer (score 0):

Yo creo que puedes utilizar la técnica de dibujar con el canvas como se muestra en este enlace: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28458818/draw-a-circle-over-a-image-in-html5-and-javascript

Comment: No se usar ese metodo broth